# EF select is not getting record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a large project with lots of data access going on. I just added a new table (from db) and the standard EF query is not working, but a sql query works.

Here's the data access:

```
public Topic GetTopicByName(string name) ... name value is KboInterestingTopic
{
    var topics = from t in _db.Topics
        where t.Name == name
        select t;

    return topics.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here's the sql that works (using the same key as  the ef query:

```
SELECT * FROM Topic
WHERE Name = 'KboInterestingTopic'
```

... It looks as if the generated select is bad, look at the last line??

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[TopicID] AS [TopicID], 
[Extent1].[TopicGUID] AS [TopicGUID], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[SETitle] AS [SETitle], 
[Extent1].[SEDescription] AS [SEDescription], 
[Extent1].[SEKeywords] AS [SEKeywords], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Extent1].[RequiresDisclaimer] AS [RequiresDisclaimer], 
[Extent1].[XmlPackage] AS [XmlPackage], 
[Extent1].[ExtensionData] AS [ExtensionData], 
[Extent1].[ShowInSiteMap] AS [ShowInSiteMap], 
[Extent1].[SkinID] AS [SkinID], 
[Extent1].[HTMLOk] AS [HTMLOk], 
[Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
[Extent1].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
[Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
[Extent1].[StoreID] AS [StoreID], 
[Extent1].[Published] AS [Published], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedOn] AS [UpdatedOn], 
[Extent1].[IsFrequent] AS [IsFrequent]
FROM [dbo].[Topic] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Name] = @p__linq__0}
```

I don't see ,@p__linq__0=N'KboInterestingTopic'

Comment: When you say it's not working what do you mean? Do you get any error? Does the code returns without an error and you get no records?

Comment: Just like what Christos said - is it possibly returning Null since you are using FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: Take it step by step. Put at breakpoint and step through _db to make sure it's instantiated and is connecting to your db properly.

Comment: Master - to get to that point in the program, the db has been queried twice - properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return _db.Topics.FirstOrDefault(
    s => s.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
);
```

Comment: It looks as if the generated select is bad, look at the last line??

Comment: I tried your query and got the same results. It's something more basic (stupid). Probably on my part. I have 100's of other ef queries that work in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Feeling very dumb ...

Working on test system - pointing to production db without the test data. It worked as expected.

Thanks for all your responses.

Abbott